# Responsive youtube video

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design

On many places I found this code to make a video responsible, but it doesn't work for me.

```
<div id='wrapp'>
<iframe id='player' src="//www.youtube.com/embed/VWSL2SykovA?rel=0"></iframe>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapp {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom:75%;  // video is 4:3 aspect ratio
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
    width:70%;
    margin:15px auto;
    z-index:2;
    border:medium ridge #b30000;
    border-radius:9px;
}
#player{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

video, i.e. iframe is too tall.
Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nhZBV/)

Comment: It's your padding-bottom:75%   .. replace it to 50%

Comment: I have a gist which shows how to render a completely responsive youtube iframe which takes into account resizing the browser width as well as the height.  You may find it useful:  https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/647fcdda17cd23715872

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shrink a Youtube video to responsive width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844500/shrink-a-youtube-video-to-responsive-width)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proportions seems to be faultives.

Try that css settings proposed by [Zurb Foundation](http://zurb.com/word/responsive-video)

```
#wrapp {
  height: 0;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 67.5%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

#player {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/nhZBV/4/)

Here's a screen capture of nhZBV/4

[image: screen capture of nhZBV/4]

Comment: Milche, do you see black bars left and right? Try to play, pls.

Comment: No, i don't see what you mean. You see them on screenshot ?

Answer (score 2):

If you apply `box-sizing: border-box;` it works fine!

**Check out updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhZBV/2/**

Comment: Works fine for me. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
#wrapp {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nhZBV/3/

Comment: SKeurentjes, your video is 16:9 tru to play and you will see black bars left and right.