# Responsive video iframes (keeping aspect ratio) with only CSS?

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I usually use a similar solution to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054426/scaling-iframes-for-responsive-design-css-only). Something like:

```
.wrapper {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.wrapper iframe {
   position:absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

But this time I have no access to the HTML or JavaScript code so I can't use a wrapper to prevent the `height:0`.

Is there a way to make an iframe responsive (and to keep the ratio) with only CSS?

Tried this (works with the iframe but not with its content):

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 33%;    
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuosf0Ly/4/)

Any thoughts? No need to support old browsers so even a CSS3 solution would be great.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the new [CSS viewport units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) `vw` and `vh` (viewport width / viewport height)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tuosf0Ly/6/)**

```
iframe {
    width: 100vw; 
    height: 56.25vw; /* 100/56.25 = 560/315 = 1.778 */
    background:red;  
}
```

Browser support is also good: IE9+ ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units))

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I updated the fiddle to mremove unnecesarry scrollbars

Comment: That only works if you want iframe to match the viewport size. However, if you need something that adapts to available width (that is, the content width of parent element of the iframe element) then you need to view the answer by SimonSimCity.

Comment: I don't like that solution because of what @MikkoRantalainen said. But instead of working with padding i'd prefer the use of images (data-uri) to make sure the aspect ratio keeps correct. See Fly1nP4nda's answer + my comment for that one. Or check that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kfafrz57/

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen you can always use `width: calc(100vw -20%)` asuming it's using only 80% of the viewport width. Probably also calc with the height would be needed.

Answer (score 87):

Here is a Fiddle for a solution, that is based on a CSS2 secret: https://jsfiddle.net/59f9uc5e/2/

```
<div class="aspect-ratio">
  <iframe src="" width="550" height="275" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<style>
/* This element defines the size the iframe will take.
   In this example we want to have a ratio of 25:14 */
.aspect-ratio {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* The height of the item will now be 56.25% of the width. */
}

/* Adjust the iframe so it's rendered in the outer-width and outer-height of it's parent */
.aspect-ratio iframe {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
</style>
```

It is explained by how percentage-values for padding are handled:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block, even for 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom'.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties

Comment: Please add a reason why I got downvoted, so I can improve my answer.

Comment: I haven't see a result on your jsfiddle link

Comment: @KemalDuran I do ... please confirm you can see iframes and have access to the youtube video. If you can't, just test it using another iframe ;) I bed your browser is one of the modern ones, right ..?

Comment: "But this time I have no access to the html code or the javascript so I can't use a wrapper to prevent the height:0"

Comment: It may be worth noting that it won't work when `.aspect-ratio`/wrapper has set `display: grid`. With `display: block` it works just fine!

Comment: Way more flexible than the selected answer, as this will adjust to any container size, not just the viewport!

Comment: @panepeter +1, this one works great for embedding videos in online documentation where there are sidebars for navigation.

You can see an example of it in use here: https://docs.netsyms.com/docs/BinStack/Locations%20and%20Categories/

Comment: I had trouble with this answer b/c I believe something's missing. You need a parent container for the aspect-ratio div. This parent's only purpose is to set a width. It's needed b/c padding-bottom within the aspect-ratio div is actually based off the parent container's width. Your code only works b/c you've set the aspect-ratio div's width to 100% which is conveniently the same as the parent container's (the body). If you change its width (let's say 50% for half the screen), the aspect ratio's lost. But with a parent container width of 50% it works! That's why it's needed for responsiveness.

Answer (score 21):

With css [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) it's easy.

```
iframe {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
}
```

Comment: "height: auto;" is not mandatory.

Comment: I am currently learning about making iframes responsive and this is by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score 13):

**Calc** function makes it much more readable:

```
.iframe-video {
    width: 755px;
    height: 424px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: calc((100vw - 40px) / (16/9));
}
```

- `width` and `height` is size for desktop and also fallback to ancient browsers
- `40px` is margin (20 px between iframe border and viewport border on both sides)
- `16/9` is ratio of video (if you have edge-to-edge player)

Comment: if you use this one with CSS iframe, it also works without a wrapper div and scales on all devices. The height and width don't really matter anymore, it scales automatically to the width of the div it is in. Very usable for Bootstrap packages and the likes. Excellent trick this one!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

```
.wrapper iframe{
 
width: 100%; /* This Forces video to 100% of parent's width */
height:unset; /* This Overwrites the height attribute of Youtube's embed code */
aspect-ratio: 16 / 9; /* This adjusts video height to keep the desired aspect ratio*/

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
  <div style="position:relative;padding-top:56.25%;">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nckseQJ1Nlg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
      style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please add this styling to the web url content you are trying to load. It will keep the 16:9 aspect ratio.

Comment: `"But this time I have no access to the HTML"`

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of hackish however you can use images to preserve the aspect ratio of a video. For example I went to paint and saved an image of 1280 x 720 resolution to use for a 16:9 aspect ratio (in here I will just grab a blank image off the internet somewhere).

This works because if you change the width of an image while leaving height auto, vise-versa the image will automatically scale - keeping proportions.

```css
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
iframe {
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/1280x720/1280x720-ghost-white-solid-color-background.jpg" alt=""/>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HkMNOlYcpHg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Using images is the best solution, because you can easily change the size of the iframe to 50% of the viewport (or 20%, or whatever you responsive website needs). But instead of loading an image over http i'd use a data-uri with an empty 16:9 image: `<img src='data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAJAIAAAP///wAAACwAAAAAEAAJAAACCoSPqcvtD6OclBUAOw=='>`

Comment: Just saw the data-uri method, that is a solid idea +1. I also want to mention that this and the image scaling method works in older browsers (mainly IE) when certain CSS3 (more awesome) properties may not be supported yet.

Comment: "But this time I have no access to the html code or the javascript so I can't use a wrapper to prevent the height:0"

Comment: Or consider using SVG for the placeholder: `<!-- Placeholder --><svg viewBox="0 0 RATIO_WIDTH RATIO_HEIGHT" style="display: block; width: 100%;"></svg>`.