# How to preserve grid layout across devices using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

I am building a website using Bootstrap v.3 which needs to be consistent across devices. I want the same layout to  be maintained across all the devices. I have used the following code to display two youtube videos side by side.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7" id="introduction">
            <p>The project uses Machine Learning to identify the waste items. A brief introduction about the Machine Learning technology is provided in the video below.
            </p>
            <iframe width="500" height="205" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yofjFQddwHE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">

            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7YgnJELpMyE?ecver=2" width="450" height="305" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The site looks like this on Desktop -

[image: Desktop version]

However, on mobile phone, it looks like this.

[image: Mobile phone]

As you can see, the layout changes inspite of having `col-md-*` `col-sm-*` and `col-xs-*` values same. Please help.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: ver 3.3 . imported via CDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note for TwBs v4 users: replace `col-xs-*` with `col-*`.

---

**Original answer** (TwBs v3) : Your `col-*` classes apply perfectly fine.

And Bootstrap is *mobile first* which means `col-xs-7` doesn't need `col-sm-7`, `col-md-7` or above.

You can check it by selecting the elements and watching their *bounding-rect-box*'es (which are highlighted by most dev-tools). However, this doesn't stop `<iframe>` elements (which have hardcoded `width` and `height` properties) to overflow the widths of their parents. If you want to override that, you need to set their `width` to `100%`:

```
iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

See it working:

```css
iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7" id="introduction">
      <p>The project uses Machine Learning to identify the waste items. A brief introduction about the Machine Learning technology is provided in the video below.
      </p>
      <iframe width="500" height="205" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yofjFQddwHE" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7YgnJELpMyE?ecver=2" width="450" height="305" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you apply it and it doesn't work, it means different CSS rules are applied on those properties by stronger selectors in your project, leaving you two options:

- find and disable those rules (you can inspect element to find all rules currently applying to it)
- use stronger (more specific) selectors in your CSS (you can find plenty of online resources explaining the principles of CSS specificity - remember the stronger your selector, the harder you're making it for yourself to modify it later. Ideally one should always use the least specific selectors applying the desired rules, thus ensuring they any future mods are easy to apply).

*Note*: most likely, `iframe` selector is not strong enough for your project. You might use an `#id`, a `.class` or, if you don't want to change the markup by adding any extra classes or ids, you can use the negation to inflate its specificity:

```
iframe:not(#_):not(#_)` { /* css rules here */ }
```

Comment: It's a common problem. It was answered [many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25302836/responsive-video-iframes-keeping-aspect-ratio-with-only-css). You should probably go with the second answer, the one using a `%` value for `padding-bottom`. The biggest value of [SO] is that the answers to common problems are given once and everyone with a similar problem can benefit from them.