# iframe not pushing the div below it down when content expands

Tags: html, css, iframe

The `<iframe>` I am using is not being responsive and not pushing the div below (footer) down. You can see the page and check the code with dev tools at:
http://www.commercetools.com/en/positions/

Is there something I can do in order to fix it, or is it a issue within the iframe itself, that I cannot fix and need to contact the people who made it?

Comment: It isn't very clear what is the behavior you expect... Can you describe more ? Do you expect the iframe to grow according to its content ?

Comment: Your iframe contains a height attribute with a value `200px`

Comment: you may set the CSS style min-height for your iframe if you want it have default height in order to make the footer look nice

Comment: Yes, it should expand the div it is in, when the content is longer. The current height is in `px` as it is semi-functional, it does not take a value of 100% for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `<iframe>` "is not being responsive":

I have what seems to be responsive `<iframe>` code. See [this Pen](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/QbaJxQ/) on Codepen. (Note: the embedded site used in the Pen is a parallax site. Although the `<iframe>` is responsive, the parallax functionality is lost at mobile sizes. Non-parallax sites seem to function correctly. Try **href="http://www.popularmechanics.com/space/a11137/secrets-of-the-water-bear-the-only-animal-that-can-survive-in-space-17069978/"** as an example.)

The markup and CSS were developed from three sources:

1. The Stack Overflow Thread [Scaling iframes for responsive design CSS-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054426/scaling-iframes-for-responsive-design-css-only?rq=1),
2. The Ben Marshall article [How to Make Responsive Iframes — it’s easy!](http://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/), and
3. The Rachel McCollin article [Making Embedded Content Work In Responsive Design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/27/making-embedded-content-work-in-responsive-design/).

Three salient points are:

- Specify *no* attributes in the opening `<iframe>` tag other than **src**, specifically *not* **height** and **width**.
- Wrap the `<iframe>` in both an inner `<div>` and an outer `<div>`.
- Style the inner `<div>` inline with **style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; overflow: auto"** which are necessary for proper scrolling and overflow handling on mobile devices but which are unstable in CSS. (I found this in a fourth article; I did not save the reference and cannot find it again.)

The rationale behind the markup structure and CSS can be found in the cited sources.

I hope this helps.