# How do i center Youtube Video (iframe) in twitter bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, youtube, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5-video

Hi I am trying to center the iframe for a Youtube video in Twitter Boostrap 3, currently it is left aligned.

I have used the following html:

```
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  
       src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" 
       align="center" id="videothumbnail"></iframe>

       </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #videothumbnail{
    height: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    float: center;}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shrink a Youtube video to responsive width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844500/shrink-a-youtube-video-to-responsive-width)

Comment: @dcc this is definitely not a duplicate of that question. This question is talking about how to use classes that are built into the Bootstrap from Twitter framework, Version 3.

Answer (score 15):

Use classes `col-xs-12 text-center`.  You don't need `float:center;`

So change this:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
```

to

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 col-xs-12 text-center">
```

Comment: I think the class you are looking for is text-center not center-text

Answer (score 8):

I was able to center my embed-responsive by bordering it with smaller grids like so:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-2'></div>
    <div class='col-sm-8'>
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qt7DFLovvD8?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add the class `col-sm-offset-2` to your centered div instead of having an empty one before.

Answer (score 4):

Just add center tags

```
<center>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  id="videothumbnail" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" align="center"></iframe>
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 2):

If working with Bootstrap 4 you could use offset.

```
<div class="col-sm-8 offset-md-2 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="750" height="415" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{your-video}" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
</div>
```

This limites the embed to 8 columns and keeps 2 columns either side of it blank (totalling 12).

Answer (score 0):

wrap the iframe with h(1-2-3...)

```
<h4 class="text-center">   <iframe ....> </iframe>    </h4>
```

Comment: Wouldn't just the class do the text align if placed on any element? Why is your answer better than the other ones given a few years back?

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class='row text-center'>


    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Qt7DFLovvD8?modestbranding=1&showinfo=0" allowfullscreen>

        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.