# How to center responsive embedd bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to center my layout developed using bootstrap 3 and no matter what I try from previous threads, it doesn't seem to center.

I currently have this as the code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 text-center"> <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" style="max-width:853px; max-height:480px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLOStnEM‌​8wBObKeWWFuh5zqac5d8‌​XMZcfe"></iframe> </div>
```

Do I need to change the CSS? Is there something I am missing here?

Here is where I am having the issue. [startupmarketing.tammycamp.com](http://startupmarketing.tammycamp.com)

I actually tried all the the options here and none of them worked:

[How do i center Youtube Video (iframe) in twitter bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560954/how-do-i-center-youtube-video-iframe-in-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `center-block` class not `text-center` To centre a div using bootstrap. Text center will centre the the text, you want the container.

You also want to apply it to your div with class `embed-responsive` so that it centres within the row.

Info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center

Edit: Looking at how your code is set up now. Remove what you currently have and replace it with the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 center-block" style="max-width: 853px;">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" style="max-width:853px; max-height:480px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLOStnEM8wBObKeWWFuh5zqac5d8XMZcfe"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see we are wrapping the embed `div` in a `.row` class and we are adding an inline style of `max-width:853px` to match your `iframe` elements size. This allows the browser to calculate the size of the child `div` in the `row` class and allows Bootstraps inbuilt `.center-block` class to work

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  I did follow your instructions and modified the code to the page as follows and it still did not work.  Any ideas?

`<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 text-center">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" style="max-width:853px; max-height:480px;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLOStnEM8wBObKeWWFuh5zqac5d8XMZcfe"></iframe>
  </div>`

Comment: Can you update your question with your current code please?

Comment: But wouldn't that we weird? The responses would be different.

Comment: Doesn't matter, I've looked at your current code on your live site and adapted that code to center your video

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at your source code. Try adding a container around the div and centering it within the container using center-block. In order for bootstrap to work properly, you need either .container or .container-fluid class if using grid system.