# Vimeo player fullscreen in background

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo

I have used this code to put my vimeo video in *background* that autoplays.

I found away to do this via css, however it only works in the console, but I can't seem to make work when I use my css file. I can't access inside the `iframe` through css.

Is there a easy way I can do this method via the `iframe` url to make it **full length and responsive**?

**Code**

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?background=1" width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Might be helpful article -- [Can I create custom settings for all my embedded videos](https://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos#can-i-create-custom-settings-for-all-my-embedded-videos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle of a responsive background video](https://jsfiddle.net/3gmmtsjc/1/). I adapted the CSS from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15844500/5764553) to make the video responsive.

To make it a background, I added this:

```
.videowrapper {
  /* ... */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, to use the official Vimeo solution of adding the parameter background=1 to the video url, you do need to be paying for Vimeo Plus.

Ref: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/224969968-Embedding-videos-overview