# Displaying a YouTube video with iframe full width of page

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube

I've put a video in my site using an `iframe` from YouTube, while the `iframe` is full width (`100%`) the video is very small (height) within the frame. How do I make it fit the width of the container?

Code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5m_ZUQTW13I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

See screenshot

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shrink a YouTube video to responsive width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844500/shrink-a-youtube-video-to-responsive-width)

Comment: You are try to making background or just full page video?

Comment: Please show code you are using so we can give you a possible solution

Comment: Another quick fix is to use ```transform: scale(2);``` and give the iframe a lower ```z-index```

Comment: A video attempting to overlap a container, with high z-index, will still get clipped if the container or its parents have overflow: hidden, or auto, in its definition.  Track down the definition and override it locally with overflow: visible, or use the transform trick to start a new z stack.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

To make a You Tube Video full width and preserve the height (and keep it responsive) you can use the following setup.

```css
.videoWrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

.videoWrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoWrapper">
  <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
  <iframe width="560" height="349" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason the video is not showing up on Google Chrome on Android. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Adding source: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: Why the padding-top: 25px; ?

Comment: Use https in the youtube URL when possible. In my case without https the video wouldn't show in Chrome.

Comment: Use www.youtube-nocookie.com when embedding stuff from them on your site.

Answer (score 30):

The issue is that an iframe and video can't scale like an image, where it gets the proportionally correct height based on the aspect ratio if you just leave the height at the default.

A solution for this is to figure out the native width/height of your video, and do a little math to figure out what the height should be at 100% screen width. Assuming it's 1920x1080, you can do something like this using viewport width (vw). You can reduce the 100vw to whatever fits better, if you don't want it to literally fill the screen.

```
iframe{
 width: 100vw
 height: calc(100vw/1.77);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Use `height: calc(100vw/1.77777778);` to remove extra black line.

Answer (score -3):

Use the fullscreen attribute:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <iframe id="myFrame" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7qWa52k-nE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </body>
</html>
```

If it not worked then also include the following css code:

```
#myFrame{
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```