# Fitting a YouTube iframe (both horizontally and vertically) without black bars

Tags: html, css

I want to fit a YouTube iframe embed in the middle of a page (70% width) so I'm doing this:

```
.wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.wrapper iframe {   
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is, I'm getting black bars around the video to fill the available space. If instead I used padding (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38270745)) the iframe would only fit horizontally and might require scrolling in the vertical direction. Any idea what might help? (older browser support is not an issue)

Edit: I know the aspect ratio of the video I want to play.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use flex css for this issue. you can use the static height width to the iframe as per your requirement

```
.wrapper  {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.wrapper iframe{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't remove the black bars and also doesn't make the iframe fit the window.

Answer (score 0):

Black bars appear when the height/width ratio of the iframe is too high (over .5, approximately).

Use this CSS to maintain a fixed height/width ratio, even when the wrapper is resized:

```
.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  padding-top: 35%; // 35/70 = 0.5, the ratio can be changed here
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper iframe {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
}
```

Comment: This removes the black bars and makes the video fit horizontally, but not vertically.

Comment: then wrap the wrapper inside a div with the following css: `display: flex; align-items: center;`

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference at all.