# Bootstrap Responsive Video Height Issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, html5-video

I have a responsive video in a Bootstrap site.

```
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="videoPlayer col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 embed-responsive embed-responsive-16x9">

        <video src="myVideo.mp4" controls class="videoItem embed-responsive-item"></video>

    </div>

</div>
```

The videoPlayer div height stays at one, but I want the video to be responsive width a max-width of 720px with corresponding height at 480px.

```
.videoItem {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: You might find this helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844500/shrink-a-youtube-video-to-responsive-width

Comment: That sure did do the trick