# How to made html map responsive without jquery plugins in React JS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My project is with a react and I don't want to use jquery plugins, tell me is there any possibility

Comment: You mean `<map>`? If yes. Same way as video or iframe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844500/shrink-a-youtube-video-to-responsive-width/15844571#15844571

Comment: What do you mean by map? What does that have to do with jQuery plugins?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p7EyT/ Hope this will help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is not very descriptive, but you can always use an event listener to adjust your map like

```
state = {
    windowHeight: undefined,
    windowWidth: undefined
  }

  handleResize = () => this.setState({
    windowHeight: window.innerHeight,
    windowWidth: window.innerWidth
  });

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleResize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize)
  }
```

Then just use the height and width from state to style your map, make sure to remove it when the page unmounts.